# VBA Runtime Error 3131 MS access 2016 Pro Plus

Tags: vba, ms-access

so the below code says there is an issue; however, I can not figure it out.

I am trying to create a search form, and VBA keeps telling me this is wrong.  I am not at all a coding person, but just doing this for a project I'm on. any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub search_Click()
Dim strsearch As String
Dim Task As String
'Check if a keyword entered or not
If IsNull(Me.txtSearch) Or Me.txtSearch = "" Then
   MsgBox "Please type last name of client.", vbOKOnly, "Keyword Needed"
   Me.txtSearch.BackColor = vbYellow
   Me.txtSearch.SetFocus
Else
    strsearch = Me.txtSearch.Value
    Task = "SELECT * FROM tbl_table-application WHERE ((Last_Name Like ""*" & strsearch & "*""))"
**   Me.RecordSource = Task**
   Me.txtSearch.BackColor = vbWhite
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error code for the issue, and on which line is the error being generated?

Comment: Instead of setting RecordSource property, I prefer to set Filter and FilterOn properties. What is the exact error message?

Answer (score 1):

Table name has hyphen character so need to enclose in [ ]: `[tbl_table-application]`. Advise not to use spaces nor punctuation/special characters in naming convention. Only underscore is acceptable exception that will work without [ ].